# Does Fingers of Frost cause frost specs to act as if the target is frozen?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If Fingers of Frost is active on a target, will Frostbolt, Frostfire bolt, and other spells behave as if the target is frozen?

Comment: Has this question been answered or not? My answer's been around for a while and was posted less than an hour after you asked the question and you still have not shown any sign that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. If Fingers of frost is successful, the target is considered to be frozen without actually being frozen. Spells that have a particular effect when a target is frozen will still benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

Finger of Frost doesn't activate on a target, it activates on yourself. According to the talent tooltip it will affect only Ice Lance and Deep Freeze, treating those spells as if the target was frozen for validity/damage purposes (for example Ice Lance will do its bonus damage against frozen targets). In short, no, other spells will NOT be treated as if the target is frozen.